# Algorithm for permutations of given characters with repetition with conditions C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation

So I need to make a program that lists all permutations.
There are 4 characters:
"1",
"2",
"R",
"T"
The conditions is that the "R" needs to have "1" before and after him so it sits like this 1-R-1
The "T" condition is that either "1" or "2" are after him so it sits like this T-1 or T-2

The max length should be 10

The output should be like this:

```
111
112
121
122
1R1
1T1
1T2
211
212
221
222
2T1
2T2
T11
T12
T21
T22
```

I have managed to figure out the permutations part but I just cannot make them work with the conditions

```
    void displayPermutation(string permutation[], int length){
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<length;i++){
            cout<<permutation[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    void getPermutations(string operatorBank[], int operatorCount, 
            string permutation[],int permutationLength, int curIndex){
        int i;
        //stop recursion condition
        if(curIndex == permutationLength){
            displayPermutation(permutation,permutationLength);
        }
        else{
            for(i = 0; i < operatorCount; i++){
                permutation[curIndex] = operatorBank[i];
                getPermutations(operatorBank,operatorCount,permutation,
                    permutationLength,curIndex+1);
            }
        }
    }

    int main ()
   {
       int operatorCount = 4;
       int permutationLength = 3;
       string operatorBank[] = {"1","2","R","T"};
       string permutation[] = {"","","",""}; //empty string
       int curIndex = 0;
       getPermutations(operatorBank,operatorCount,permutation,
                                   permutationLength,curIndex);
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) may be relevant.

Comment: sadly next_permutation doesnt work with repeating characters

Comment: *sadly next_permutation doesnt work with repeating characters* -- Create an array of indices, `0` to `n-1` and permute those.  Then those indices indicate what character to select.

Comment: @jebotekurac  There are no repeating characters.  But 3 symbols. '1R1', 'T1' and 'T2', which are only needed for printing, or further processing.  The permutations can be computed with 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: @jebotekurac So the `permutationCount` is not only the number of items to select, but the potential "repeat count" of a character?  The reason why I am asking is that the very first item you say is valid is `111`, even though `1` only appears once in the `operatorBank` array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie every item in the operatorBank can be used more than once. I do not know if i used the right term Permutations or should i have used the term Combinations

Comment: So basically, your string, given the number of characters is 4, expands to "111222RRRTTT" and you want to choose 3 with repeats allowed.  Is that correct?  If so, there should be a solution using the STL algorithms and containers.

Answer (score 0):

You got your terms a little mixed up. You're not talking about permutations[1] but about combinations[2].

As far as I can tell you already have the algorithm (recursive backtracking) you're just not checking if your solution is valid, by filtering the solution space. So you're generating all solutions without taking into account any constraint and you print a solution when you reached the `permutationLength`. At this step you can also check if the solution is valid by checking if it abides by the conditions. If it is you print it, if not you discard it.

Strategy for this would be:

1. Look for `R` and check if `permutation[idx-1]` is `1` and `permutation[idx+1]` is `1`
2. Look for `T` and check if `permutation[idx+1]` is either `1` or `2`.

You only print the solution if these conditions are met!

```
...
if(curIndex == permutationLength){
    if (solutionValid()) {
          displayPermutation(permutation,permutationLength);
    }
}
...
```

1. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Permutation.html
2. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Combination.html

Comment: Actually, this is neither a permutation (a rearrangement of a sequence) nor a combination (an unordered selection of elements of a set). (According to wolfram's definitions, which are certainly reasonable.) It's an enumeration (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Enumerate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a recursion like this?

```js
function f(n, str=""){
  if (!n)
    return [str];
    
  let result = [];
  
  if (n >= 3)
    result = result.concat(f(n - 3, str + "1R1"));
    
  if (n >= 2)
    result = result
      .concat(f(n - 2, str + "T1"))
      .concat(f(n - 2, str + "T2"));
    
  return result
    .concat(f(n - 1, str + "1"))
    .concat(f(n - 1, str + "2"));
}

console.log(f(3));
```